# MySQL Stored Procedure comparing parameter input with a table value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure which takes in a value then compares it with a table value. For example

The procedure takes in a varchar(30) value say " RED " as c_title then compares it with all the titles in a table called campaign, if matching then update some column with a certain value.

basically how would you compare two variables of string values in mysql?

I've tried different comparison methods using LIKE, IN and  =

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_finish_campaign(in c_title varchar(30)) 
Begin
Update campaign
Set TITLE = "Hello"
where TITLE = c_title;
END
```

New Title value should be hello where TITLE matches the input value

but im getting error code 1064 for syntax error.

Appreciate any feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to end your update with a semicolon, but first redefine the delimiter which will be used by the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER // ;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_finish_campaign(IN c_title varchar(30)) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE campaign
    SET TITLE = 'Hello'
    WHERE TITLE = c_title;
END //
```

Also, you should try to use *single* quotes when defining string literals in MySQL.  Double quotes most likely would work also, but they are mainly used to indicate database objects (e.g. database, table, and column names), rather than strings.